# Replacing a sublist with another list in Java in constant time

Tags: java, list, collections

Is there a List-like container in Java that provides the capability of replacing a sublist with another list in constant time, given an iterator to the start and end of the sublist?

For example I could do the following:

```
List<T> l1, l2;
ListIterator<T> i1, i2;

// Initialize the above variables correctly...

l1.replace(i1, i2, l2);
```

If I was rolling my own linked list, this would be easy so I'd assume this is a feasible task using Collections.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this in constant time using the built-in APIs.

> If I was rolling my own linked list, this would be easy so I'd assume this is a feasible task using Collections.

Not quite.  Even rolling your own implementation, you can't do this in constant time in a way that

- would only change `l1`, not `l2`
- would let you do the same operation more than once, perhaps with `l3` and `l2`

It is easy to imagine that if this were built into the JDK APIs, these problems could result in accidental behavior that was really unpleasant to debug.

Comment: You are correct about the behavior of this affecting l2. In my case this doesn't matter since l2 is created strictly for the purpose of inserting into l1 and never accessed otherwise. It makes sense that this is not generally desirable behavior. I hadn't thought about the side effects. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AbstractList.html#addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Comment: Not sure where that guarantee's anywhere that the replacing happens in constant time. Afaik it actually will iterate over each element in the sublist and add it to current list.

Comment: What about removing? removeAll seems to be equivalent to remove if there is a match. Also is there an implementation of AbstractList that implements addAll in O(1) time?